# How to make Chrometype Potrait in Blender?

Tags: rendering

### Chrometype Potrait

I saw this [video](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/u9c22p/mechanized_anguish_ii/) on reddit and wanted to recreate this effect in Blender but the only nearest thing I have found is this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGHrDgRRnws). However, this tutorial was made for Cinema 4D users. Can anyone give a detailed method as to how to recreate the effect in Blender? (Please try to include lightning, node setup and other important stuff as well).

(Cycles render engine to be used)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I didn't study your tutorial link ... so just a few tips since no-one provided any other answer here.*

---

You can try default Principled BSDF shader with Metallic 1, Roughness 0 or something small. Color based on ColorRamp node according to your taste (HSV gives me nicer saturated color mix than RGB). Texture coordinate looks like Layer Weight > Facing type.

[image]
[image]

For World material set Environment texture with some black&white equirectangular texture ...

[image]

Should be .exr or .hdr file type, but in this case - mainly used for reflection purpose (not lightning) a .jpg works as well.
Animate the texture in Z axis.

[image]
[image]

For final touch just enable Eevee > Bloom with some adjustments according to your world texture condition to bloom up result.

[image]

[image]